# Files created through cloud9 SSH workspace result in 404s

Tags: ssh, ftp, cloud9-ide

I've been spending some time getting Cloud9 set up for use at my company, and for the most part, everything is working fine. I've come across a very frustrating issue relating to their SSH workspaces though, and can't seem to find information about it anywhere online.

The issue is that when a file is created in the Cloud9 IDE (via control+n, or any other means - including drag and drop upload), that file results in a 404 when navigated to in a browser. The file very clearly exists, as it is editable in Cloud9, and definitely shows up when we FTP into the server and confirm it's location. But in browser the file will result in a 404.

An interesting note: if you were to take the exact same file, save it locally, and upload it to the SAME DIRECTORY through FTP, everything works as expected.

I really can't figure out how this is even possible, and it has to be some sort of quirk with SSH that I'm unfamiliar with. Anyone have experience with something like this, or any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is caused by different permissions set to files created in different ways. use `ls -la path/to/folder` command which should output something like

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 user   group   4467 May 10 01:02 server.js*
drwxr-xr-x   2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 May 10 01:02 settings/
drwxr-xr-x   2 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 May 10 01:02 test/
```

and look for differences in permissions `drwxr-xr-x` part and user/group

You can use chown and chmod commands to modify owner and permissions